# Curly brackets around items in a list (in source code) or not?

Tags: lists

To make a list, all LaTeX info that I see (for example [learnlatex.com](https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-04)) suggest the following style (I'll take itemize as example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item An entry
\item Another One
\item Wow! Three entries
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I find it easier to see the structure in the source code if the items are bracketed, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item{An entry}
\item{Another One}
\item{Wow! Three entries}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

In this simple example, the outcome is identical. I have used this for years, and never noticed any problems, and (especially in more complex situations) the curly brackets help me to visualize source code.

But in combination with different packages or changed settings, there conceivably could be a difference between the two methods. Is this a risk, and should I change my habit and remove the curly brackets here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You should add a space after `\item` to signify that what follows is not an argument of `\item` but just a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is bad style as it makes the source look as if `\item` takes an argument, but actually the braces are unrelated to the `\item` and so form a TeX group, just as if at the top level you had a grouped paragraph

```
{Some text some text...}
```

Rather than a normal ungrouped paragraph

```
Some text some text...
```

As in this case, if there are no declarations within the text it does not make a lot of difference but if there are any declarations such as a font change, then the braces scope the effect so

```
    {Some text some \bfseries text...}


    {More text more text}
```

More text is not bold, but in

```
    Some text some \bfseries text...


    More text more text
```

More text would be bold.

You will see exactly the same with your grouped paragraph texts in a list, the grouping will scope any declarations to a single item.

Comment: Good answer, I understand better what the brackets are doing, but I have to agree with the OP about the curly brackets making things clearer. I would also see the scope limitation as an advantage, not a disadvantage.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins `\item{this item} {something else}`  looks as if the item is `this item` when it is `this item something else`  so I still say that you should only add a group if you want a group, not to make things "look" like a scope of the item.

Comment:  I would never use two groups after an item without a specific need for them!